# Getting Fragment context instead of Activity when clicking on FAB

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

So I can't exactly post the entire code since it's fragmented across files but I'll try to explain as best I can.

I have android application that is structured in the following manner:

```
MainActivity
  |__Toolbar
  |__ViewPager
  |     |__DestinationListFragment
  |     |__DestinationMapFragment
  |
  |___FAB
```

The **DestinationListFragment** houses a RecyclerView which shows data from a Firebase Firestore database. The **DestinationMapFragment** does the same, except populates them on a map - for this question, this fragment is irrelevant.

The FAB is present inside the **MainActivity**'s layout because then it shows up with proper elevation and I can easily `.hide()` or `.show()` it. When clicked, it open's a dialog (whose code is in **FilterDialogFragment**) which allows the user to filter through the items.

The **FilterDialogFragment** has a FilterListener interface, like so:

```
interface FilterListener {
    void onFilter(Filters filters);
}
private FilterListener mFilterListener;
```

which is then implemented in **DestinationListFragment** like so

```
public class DestinationListFragment extends Fragment implements
        FilterDialogFragment.FilterListener,
        DestinationAdapter.OnDestinationSelectedListener {

    /* some code */

    @Override
    public void onFilter(Filters filters){
         /* some code */
    }
}
```

Now, to instantiate the `mFilterListener` in **FilterFragmentDialog**, I call the following in its `onAttach()` method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof FilterListener) {
        mFilterListener = (FilterListener) context;
    }
}
```

However, mFilterListener is never instantiated because the `context` is **MainActivity** instead of **DestinationListFragment** because that's where the FAB is located and hence, is not an instance of FilterListener. I tried moving the FAB to the **DestinationListFragment**'s layout but the context passed was still **MainActivity**'s. I can't move the code over to **MainActivity** because other methods within **DestinationListFragment** rely on it. How can I change the code so that **DestinationListFragment**'s context is passed instead of **MainActivity**'s?

I used [Firebase's sample app](https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-android) as a base for the filtering code. Everything seems to except the listener.

Comment: communicate through the hosting `Activity` -
 https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: `Fragment` is not a `Context`. `getContext()` called in a `Fragment` will always return the parent `Activity's` `Context` (or null).

Comment: So I followed @MarkKeen suggestion and hoisted the Listener up to the MainActivity. Within it, I simply call the fragment's `onFilter()`. It works as intended now! However, is this a _good_ solution? Like are there any gotchas regarding this? Thanks again btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **MainActivity** I implemented `FilterDialogFragment.FilterListener` and override `onFilter()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onFilter(Filters filters) {
    DestinationListFragment fragment = (DestinationListFragment) mPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
    fragment.onFilter(filters);
}
```